# Routing through IPSec tunnel

Tags: routing, ipsec, strongswan

I have two servers establishing an IPSec VPN as a site-to-side kind of setup. I use StrongSwan on Ubuntu 16.04 for both servers and the VPN itself works. What may be a bit special is that the subnet behind each gateway is just virtual as in I created a virtual network adapter `eth0:0`.

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address <PublicIP-A>
    ... etc

auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.6.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.6.255
```

(The second server has the `192.168.6.0/24` network and PublicIP-B, where PublicIP-A and -B are of course replaced by real and working IP addresses.)

The reason for the virtual network is that I want to connect to one of the servers through IPSec VPN tunnel and use that tunnel for SSH/FTP transfer communication. To be able to connect to the server via SSH/FTP or ping it I found I needed this virtual network. (Found that in earlier tests with a host-to-site VPN config which worked; unfortunately, that changed with my site-to-site setup.)
Is the virtual network the right approach? Is there something better?

My `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    authby=secret
    keyexchange=ike

conn net-net
    right=<PublicIP-A>
    rightsubnet=192.168.6.0/24
    left=<PublicIP-B>
    leftsubnet=192.168.5.0/24
    auto=add
```

When I `traceroute` server B's virtual network address 192.168.5.1, it tries to go through the internet instead of the tunnel, and gets stuck... So I tried setting up routes with approaches like this in various combinations - but with very limited success:

```
ip route add 192.168.5.0/24 via 192.168.6.1 dev eth0 src PublicIP-A table 220
```

I also tried some iptables settings taken from the StrongSwan documentation (https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/net2net-psk/), but didn't get it running.

I hope this setup makes sense to anyone who would help me figure out how to set-up my routing to tell traffic to the other server's virtual local network to go through the tunnel. Any more information needed - please don't hesitate...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 2016-08-26**

Thinking about @ecdsa's comment, I don't need a site-to-site setup. Site-to-host is fine.

`traceroute` output

```
traceroute to PublicIPServer-B (PublicIPServer-B), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  PublicIPServer-B (PublicIPServer-B)  1.467 ms  1.298 ms  1.229 ms
```

whereas without the tunnel some other gateways popup.

This helped to get from Server B to Host A - SSH works - But the other direction doesn't want to work. Real world setup later will be site-to-host where there's a real network behind gateway Server B.

Taken from here https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/host2host-cert/, I tried to add a route

```
ip route add PublicIPServer-B via PublicIPServer-B src PublicIPHost-A
// and
ip route add 192.168.5.0/24 via PublicIPServer-B src PublicIPHost-A
```

which results in `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable` errors. Not sure if I will ever need the host-to-site direction communication but would be nice to be on the safe side. (Especially since I'm not 100% sure if the answers to the `traceroute` are send through the tunnel)

Any ideas on how to achieve the last bit?

**EDIT 2016-08-26 (2nd)**

strongSwan apparently does set-up the routes in this scenario. `traceroute`-ing and `ping`-ing the remote subnet (as in the Server-B's remote subnet IP address 192.168.5.1) works.

So, yeah, I guess this is solved for now!

Cheers @ecdsa

Comment: What exactly is the point of the site-to-site tunnel and the virtual subnets if you only want to connect two hosts? Or is only one using a virtual subnet? And unless you disabled it (or it fails, check the log) strongSwan should already install routes in table 220 (the source address _src_ should be the one in the local virtual subnet, the gateway _via_ the local next hop).

Comment: @ecdsa, thanks for your comment. You have a point here, site-to-site is not necessary. So got a bit further but didn't solve it completely.
Didn't disable the strongSwan function to add the routes to table 220. Now discovered that it does create route but these seem incorrect as it's using `via` with i.e. Host-A-MainGatewayIP (138.55.133.1 when my host is 138.55.133.34). Why is that?

Comment: Is there a way to check if strongSwan created table 220 routes, should it appear in the logs?